# Which keyboard layout should i select for the Samsung Smart keyboard Trio 500?

Tags: keyboard-layout, wireless-keyboards

I am setting up ubuntu on my Galaxy s21 ultra via the app Adronix/Termux. I am using the [Samsung Smart keyboard Trio 500](https://www.samsung.com/nl/mobile-accessories/smart-keyboard-trio-500-black-ej-b3400ubegeu/) as a bluetooth keyboard. I have asked Samsung support which general keyboard layout this model has. They said the model has a generic 104-key layout.

But now in the next step i have to select another option related to the keyboard layout.
I can select the following options:

> 1. English (US)
> 2. English - Cherokee
> 3. ** - English(Colemak)
> 4. ** - English (Dvorak)
> 5. ** - ** (Dvorak, alt. intl.)
> 6. ** - ** (Dvorak, alt. intl. with dead keys)
> 7. ** - ** (Dvorak, left-handed)
> 8. ** - ** (Dvorak, right-handed)
> 9. ** - ** (Macintosh)
> 10. ** - ** (Norman)
> 11. ** - ** (US, Alt. intl.)
> 12. ** - ** (US, euro on 5)
> 13. ** - ** (US, intl., with dead keys)
> 14. ** - ** (Workman)
> 15. ** - ** (Workman with dead keys)
> 16. ** - ** (Classic Dvorak)
> 17. ** - ** (Programmer dvorak)
> 18. ** - ** (intl., with AltGr dead keys)
> 19. ** - ** (The divide/multiply keys toggle the layout)

The last two options are for russian or serbo-croation and thus not relevant. In the ubuntu chat it has been suggested to choose the 'auto detect layout' option. But unfortunately no such option exists in this menu.

So which one should i choose? A picture of the keyboard can be found in the link i've provided above. I am installing ubuntu v.20

Thank you

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as v.20

Comment: What's the "X11 Model" if you run the `localectl` command?